# Expo Go Stripe: Native module cannot be null

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I believe Expo-Go can now support Stripe payments (based off the updated docs provided [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/stripe/).)

I am using Expo SDK Version 40.

I perform

```
"expo install @ stripe/stripe-react-native"
```

to ensure I'm getting the correct version.

Then I attempt to import Stripe into my project using:

```
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'
```

As soon as the project refreshes, the app crashes and throws ~25 errors/warnings, most commonly the "Native module cannot be null" error

Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using Expo SDK Version 40.

You have to use a higher version like 41/42, I believe, so I'd try updating that. Per the link you shared, you'll note that https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v41.0.0/sdk/stripe/ exists but https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/stripe/ doesn't for instance.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/467#issuecomment-889217595

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/256#issuecomment-846922117

Comment: Wouldn't that mess with my entire build at that point?

Comment: It might affect some things you use, yes, but that's how Expo works with the dependences rolled in. You would need to review the breaking changes in the Expo changelog and see what you need to handle. https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this reply. This worked for me, I upgraded to SDK 42. Thank you for your assistance.